# Importing directories of resources into a JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp

Can I import an entire directory of jar files at once, or must I specify each jar individually when creating a JNLP?

If the latter, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I import an entire directory of jar files at once, ..

No.

> ..or must I specify each jar individually when creating a JNLP?

Yes.

> ..If the latter, are there any workarounds?

There ain't no workaround, cos' it ain't broke.  That is the way JWS is supposed to work.  You don't just toss every single resource on the file system at it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way is to specify them individually.  If the problem is you have several common jars in multiple JNLP files.  I think you can create one JNLP file with the common jars and link it as an extension in the specific JNLP files that need it.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not have the concept of "directory". So, your JNLP client would not have a chance to get the list of files and then fetch them all.